# Name That... Name?

Tags: riddle, language

A ton of shackles trapped in ice

A black man who is green seems nice

A group of two Englishmen with love for different girls

A man of small units makes chemists go for a whirl

People don't take this concept so mild

But what is this name that has an importance so Wilde

Hint

> The first four lines in the rhyme reference 4 different people that had the mystery name

Comment: (Your last line may have made the answer too obvious.. but i'll wait until i get the others before i post an answer)

Comment: Personally I think the *first* line made the answer too obvious :-).

Comment: Sorry if I made it obvious. I actually want to try and make this Name that Name thing a series.

Comment: Is it Rot13(Bfpne)? First guess from the last word of the last line (excluding the hint) :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Ernest!

A ton of shackles trapped in ice

> Ernest Shackleton

A black man who is green seems nice

> Ernest Green: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernest_Green

A group of two Englishmen with love for different girls

> The importance of being Earnest

A man of small units makes chemists go for a whirl

> Ernest Rutherford(Rutherford is a very small unit)

But what is this name that has an importance so Wilde

> Well, he wrote the importance of being Earnest

Comment: Have a look at this rot13(uggcf://ra.jvxvcrqvn.bet/jvxv/Rearfg_Terra)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but I thought it was rather obscure and 'forcing'. Will add it to my answer since it seems it wasn't just me :)

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

A ton of shackles trapped in ice

> [Ernest Shackleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endurance_(1912_ship))

A black man who is green seems nice

> [John Stewart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Stewart_(comics)) (thanks to @Saeïdryl) or [CeeLo Green](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CeeLo_Green) (thanks to @Bálint Budavölgyi)

But what is this name that has an importance so Wilde

> Oscar maybe

Comment: I think the second one could be rot13(Prr Yb Terra) :D

Comment: Could also be rot13(Wbua Fgrjneq) for the second one because yours well, is white

Comment: Which one of mine is white?
And who is Wbua Fgrjneq and how can he be Green? @Saeïdryl

Comment: @prit.patel (Mistake : Stewart* and not Steward) He is a Green Lantern too

Comment: One of these first names is correct